# Prove an equation is decreasing

Tags: derivatives

I have spent more than an hour on this question and it is driving me nuts: [image]

Somehow my working indicates the equation should be increasing because $0 < W(T) < K$. Can any kind soul help me out? It is the last step that I do not know.

I have difficulties proving W(T) is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Did you try to find the derivative of W(T)?

Comment: Please use **MathJax** to format math and avoid making the question too specific to your personal situation. Welcome to SE!

Comment: $W(t)$ is the average of a decreasing function. By the way, an equation cannot be increasing.

Comment: Have you evaluated the integral?

Comment: Hi all, I evaluated the  derivative. Assume the weird sign = a for the time being.
W'(T) is K(1+aT-e^-aT) / [(e^aT)aT^2]

In addition, it is a general question because I have no idea how to tackle other similar questions.

Comment: @math I only have issues proving the derivative is strictly decreasing. My derivative corresponds with the official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:
$$1) \ 1+x\le e^x, \ \ \ x\in (-\infty, +\infty).$$
$$2) \ e^{-pT}Tp+e^{-pT}-1=\frac{1+Tp-e^{Tp}}{e^{Tp}}.$$

Comment: Hi @farruhota, you are a genius. I managed to solve it. May I know how you manage to derive the first equation? Would like to know more of such inequalities.

Comment: Hi. It is just a tangent line to $e^x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I  just realise it is simple geometry... I was too fixated with the correlation between p and T.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we get $$\int e^{-{\rho t}}dt=-\frac{e^{-\rho t}}{\rho}+C$$
and the definite integral$$\frac{K}{T}\int_{0}^T e^{-\rho t}dt=-{\frac {K \left( -1+{{\rm e}^{-\rho\,T}} \right) }{\rho\,T}}$$
the first derivative with respect to $T$ is given by $$W'(T)={\frac {K \left( {{\rm e}^{-\rho\,T}}T\rho+{{\rm e}^{-\rho\,T}}-1
 \right) }{{T}^{2}\rho}}
$$
$$W'(T)<0$$ gives $$T\rho+1<e^{\rho T}$$
$$W'(T)<o$$ is equivalent to $${\frac {K \left( {{\rm e}^{-\rho\,T}}T\rho+{{\rm e}^{-\rho\,T}}-1
 \right) }{{T}^{2}\rho}}
<0$$
since $$K,T^2\rho>0$$ we get
$$e^{-\rho T}T\rho+e^{-\rho T}-1<0$$

Comment: Hi @dr, I have no issues with the integral and derivative. I only have problem proving it is decreasing. Thanks for the integral but i have no issues with that. I evaluated the derivative. Assume the weird sign = a for the time being. W'(T) is K(1+aT-e^-aT) / [(e^aT)aT^2]

Comment: Hi @dr, i got to W'(T) part and I am stuck at proving W(T) is strictly decreasing. I used 0 < W(T) < K but i only get W(T) as strictly increasing.

Comment: is given that $$\rho>0$$?

Comment: Hi @dr p>0, K>0, T^2 > 0. [Tp(e^-pT) + e^(-pT) - 1] must < 0 for W(T) to be strictly decreasing. However, I cannot prove 1 > Tp(e^-pT) + e^(-pT). In addition, I extract e^-pT from the top because it is definitely positive.

Comment: Hi @dr I have issues proving that the derivative of the equation is negative not the other way round...

Answer (score 0):

$W(T)$ is a decreasing function if and only if $W'(T) < 0$. Note that $$e^x = 1+x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots .$$ As such, $$e^{-x} = \frac{1}{1+x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots} < \frac{1}{1+x}.$$
I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Math, this looks plausible but Farruhota's method is more straightforward. Would love to try your method out first thing in the morning.

Comment: Thanks. Both are equivalent. You have to prove e^(-ax)(1+ax)-1<=0. Equivalently, e^(-ax) <=1/(1+ax).

Comment: Hi @Math, I just noticed the Euler's pattern. This method is an eye-opener.